# Highcharts crosshair with labels on axes

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, tooltip

Is it possible to make highcharts crosshair that vill show actual value on the axis in the separate label?

Regular crosshair example out from API doesnt do this. If I set

```
tooltip: {
        crosshairs: [true, true]
    }
```

, it doesnt do what I need. 
I need chart to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just general idea: http://jsfiddle.net/r7fdh/ - you need to add checking if cursor is inside plot (use `chart.plot[Left/Top/Width/Height]`) and you may need to use something else than `event.page[X/Y]` for getting position.

Code:

```
$("#container").mousemove(move);

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});

function move(event) {
    var x = event.pageX,
        y = event.pageY,
        path = ['M', chart.plotLeft, y,
            'L', chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth, y,
            'M', x, chart.plotTop,
            'L', x, chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight];

    if (chart.crossLines) {
        // update lines
        chart.crossLines.attr({
            d: path
        });
    } else {
        // draw lines
        chart.crossLines = chart.renderer.path(path).attr({
            'stroke-width': 2,
            stroke: 'green',
            zIndex: 10
        }).add();
    }

    if (chart.crossLabel) {
        // update label
        chart.crossLabel.attr({
            y: y + 6,
            text: chart.yAxis[0].toValue(y).toFixed(2)
        });
    } else {
        // draw label
        chart.crossLabel = chart.renderer.text(chart.yAxis[0].toValue(y).toFixed(2), chart.plotLeft - 40, y + 6).add();
    }
}
```

Comment: Improved version, with checking the `x,y` position: http://jsfiddle.net/mr1c03ae/

Answer (score 8):

This is implemented in the Highstock API, see http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.crosshair.label.

In order to use it with Highcharts, just load highstock.js and initialize a regular Highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/vmyau00g/

```
            crosshair: {
                label: {
                    enabled: true,
                    padding: 8
                }
            }
```

Comment: I think crosshairs with labels on the Y axis make sense for regular bar/line charts, not just for stock charts, so I would suggest porting this feature to Highcharts.

Answer (score -1):

Defaulty it is not possible, but you can set mouseover/mouse events and use renderer to add custom shape/object.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer